# Weird for loop math

Tags: java, for-loop, do-while

```
int i = 3, j = 3;
for (; i++ == j--; i += 2, j -= 2) {
    do {
        i = i + j;
    } while (i % j != 0);
}
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(j);
```

I tried debugging it in Eclipse, and here's the result:

- i,j
- 3,3
- 4,2
- 6,2
- 9,-1

Since the last time for loop checked the values of i and j, they were not equal to each other, why did it came out of the loop? Wouldn't it be an infinite loop?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve??

Comment: Since `i++ != j--`, it exits the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (; ++i != --j; i += 2, j -= 2) {}
```

Condition `++i != --j` or `i++ != --j` or `++i != j--` will cause infinite loop.

i++ and j-- both are post increment and decrements respectively so first it will check the condition and later increment the value.

Answer (score 1):

They were not equal to each other so loop terminated .If they were equal loop will not terminate this is your condition.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not run into the infinite loop
1. i and j are initialized (i=3, j=3)
2. condition is checked. And after checking the condition the value changes (i=3, j=2)  --> *Post increment and post decrement*
3. Inside do while loop.. i=4 and j remains same (j=2)
4. The condition of do while loop breaks. as (6%2 != 0 ==> returns false)
5. Now third portion of for loop executes which makes i=6 and j=0
6. Now conditional section executes. Which returns false and then changes the value of i and j as (i=9 and j=-1)

And then they print the values as i=9 and j=-1

If it would have been *pre increment and pre decrement* then they will run into infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

You could change your code to while() loops as below:
(I replaced i, j to m,  n respectively)

```
int m = 3, n = 3;
while( m++ == n-- ){    //Initially m and n are 3
    //m becomes 4 due to ++
    //n becomes 2 due to --

    m = m + n;  //m becomes 6 
    while( m % n != 0){ // 6 % 2 is 0
        m = m + n;  // Not called
    }

    m = m + 2; // m becomes 8
    n = n - 2; // n becomes 0

   //Goes back to the while(m++ == n--) to check condition again. 
   //However ( 8++ == 0--) is false, so while loop is not called again.
   //but, the values of m and n change to 9 and -1 respectively. 
}
```

Mixing various types of loops might make things a little complicated to debug.

Comment: Well, you could keep the do-while as it is. I took out `m=m+n;` from inner while loop to make the code work same as do-while.